# Laravel - strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to  group tags by first character

```
return $tags->select('id', 'title')
    ->orderBy('title','asc')
    ->groupBy(function($item, $key) { 
        return substr($item['title'], 1, 1); 
    })
    ->get();
```

but it returns this error

> strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Is the error from a Laravel file, or by you own code?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call `strtolower`?

Comment: i think its error is from this part

groupBy(function($item, $key) { 
        return substr($item['title'], 1, 1); 
    })

Comment: i am not calling strtolower

Comment: PHP errors usually have file & line specified. It'd be useful if you specified the full error here. Other suggestion would be using xdebug which also allows you to have backtraces displayed on errors. Then you'd know where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't group the query using a closure, only the resulting collection:

```
...->orderBy(...)->get()->groupBy(...);
```