# PHP function stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm running through Laravel 6.0's `addSelect()` method as the official documentation described. However, I'm getting an error as my title suggested.

Two corresponding tables are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `destinations` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `flights` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
 `destination_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `arrived_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The corresponding controller:

```php
use App\Flight;
use App\Destination;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function Index()
    {
        return Destination::addSelect(['last_flight' => 
            Flight::select('name')
            ->whereColumn('destination_id', 'destinations.id')
            ->orderBy('arrived_at', 'desc')
            ->limit(1)
        ])->get();
    }
}
```

What is the object provided as a parameter, which is responsible for the error?

Comment: Checkout this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016818/laravel-strtolower-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given). It might all you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016818/laravel-strtolower-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given)